# How can I pass a UIEvent to a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwindow, uiapplication

I am subclassing UIWindow and creating an implementation of sendEvent: as follows:

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super sendEvent:event];

    // Send event to UIScrollView here
}
```

How can I send the event to a UIScrollView.  I tried calling the touchesBegan:, etc. messages, but that did not do anything.

Comment: What do you want to do that differs from the inherited behavior?

Comment: I need something under the UIScrollView to get the event first, so I set userInteractionEnabled on the UIScrollView to NO.  Then, I want to "copy" the event and pass it to the scroll view.